# Node xmlbuilder mod TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the [node xmlbuilder module](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js), and [copied / pasted their code from here](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki/Conversion-From-Object) but I get a

> **Converting circular structure to JSON error**.

I have no clue why this is happening, here is the code:

**Route:**

```
app.get('/api/qb', function(req, res) {
  qbwc.test(req, function(result){
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

**Module:**

```
exports.test = function(data, next) {
  var obj = {
    person: {
      name: "John",
      '@age': 35,
      address: {
        city: "Istanbul"
      },
      phone: [
        {
          '#text': "555-1234",
          '@type': 'home'
        }, {
          '#text': "555-1235",
          '@type': 'mobile'
        }
      ],
      id: function() {
        return 42;
      }
    }
  };

  var root = builder.create(obj);
  return next(root);

}
```

**EDIT:**
I also tried it with something very simple to test, same issue:

```
var obj = { name: 'smith'};
var root = builder.create(obj);
return next(root);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of hair pulling, it seems you need to call .end() on the process, I have no idea why they don't have this in the example.

Here is what you need to do:

```
  ...
  var root = builder.create(obj);
  root = root.end({pretty: false});
  return next(root);
```